# Can I Tweet an image with just a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter

I'm setting up the back end for an Android/iOS app that, among other things, allows users to share an image via Twitter. It's hosted on Heroku, which has no local image hosting, so the images are hosted elsewhere.

It looks like if you want to tweet an image you're supposed to POST to [/statuses/update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) and send the image as multi-part data. But I don't have the images stored locally, so I would have to copy the image over to temp storage on Heroku, POST it to Twitter, and then delete it, which seems... inefficient.

Is there any way I can use Twitter's API to tweet an image and only supply the URL for the image?

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like it's possible to send Twitter a link via their API, presumably because they would then have to download the image themselves. You could upload the image to a third party and link to that, but you have the same problem in that case.

You shouldn't need to copy the file over as such though, you could read the file into memory and serialize it to multi-part form data in order to send to Twitter.

Do you have any code to show?

Comment: I'm relatively new to RoR & have *no* idea how to read the file into memory and then serialize into form data; can you point me to the right methods on apidock.com or ruby-doc.org?

Comment: Where are your files currently hosted?

Comment: Currently on some other hosting we have, though the plan is to move them over to Amazon S3 before launch.